# What is the Iterable interface used for?

Tags: java, iterable

I am a beginner and I cannot understand the real effect of the `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Besides what Jeremy said, its main benefit is that it has its own bit of syntactic sugar: the [enhanced for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). If you have, say, an `Iterable<String>`, you can do:

```
for (String str : myIterable) {
    ...
}
```

Nice and easy, isn't it? All the dirty work of creating the `Iterator<String>`, checking if it `hasNext()`, and calling `str = getNext()` is handled behind the scenes by the compiler.

And since most collections either implement `Iterable` or have a view that returns one (such as `Map`'s `keySet()` or `values()`), this makes working with collections much easier.

The [`Iterable` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) gives a full list of classes that implement `Iterable`.

Answer (score 14):

If you have a complicated data set, like a tree or a helical queue (yes, I just made that up), but you *don't care* how it's structured internally, you just want to get all elements one by one, you get it to return an iterator.

The complex object in question, be it a tree or a queue or a WombleBasket implements Iterable, and can return an iterator object that you can query using the Iterator methods.

That way, you can just ask it if it `hasNext()`, and if it does, you get the `next()` item, without worrying where to get it from the tree or wherever.

Answer (score 5):

It returns an `java.util.Iterator`. It is mainly used to be able to use the implementing type in the enhanced for loop

```
List<Item> list = ...
for (Item i:list) {
 // use i
}
```

Under the hood the compiler calls the `list.iterator()` and iterates it giving you the `i` inside the for loop.

Comment: So far the best answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

An interface is at its heart a list of methods that a class should implement.  The iterable interface is very simple -- there is only one method to implement: `Iterator()`.  When a class implements the `Iterable` interface, it is telling other classes that you can get an `Iterator` object to use to iterate over (i.e., traverse) the data in the object.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators basically allow for iteration over any Collection.

It's also what is required to use Java's for-each control statement.

Answer (score 0):

The Iterable is defined as a generic type.

Iterable , where T type parameter represents the type of elements returned by the iterator.

An object that implements this interface allows it to be the target of the “foreach” statement. The for-each loop is used for iterating over arrays, collections.

read more -: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/iterable-java-example-java-lang-iterable-interface/