# How to print out individual Strings from Iterable<String>

Tags: java, iterable

I am having trouble printing out individual Strings from Interable object.
I have this given function prefixMatch(String someword) that returns Iterable (that keeps a LinkedList of Strings, I think). I have tried turning it into a list but it wont work. Dose anyone know how to get the Strings out of it one by one?

tst is a Ternary search tree

```
Iterable<String> words = tst.prefixMatch(word);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) you can do an extended for on it.

```
Iterable<String> iterable;
for(String s : iterable){
    //Do whatever you want
}
```

---

**Resources:**

- [Oracle.com - The foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

**Related topics:**

- [What is the Iterable interface used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059127/what-is-the-iterable-interface-used-for)

Answer (score 4):

```
for (String s: words) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The java 8 way, using `forEach` :

```
words.forEach(word-> System.out.println(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, here i am using Iterable.

```
TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        treeSet.add("A");
        treeSet.add("B");

        Iterable<String> it = treeSet;

        Iterator iterator = it.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());

        }
```